# Best way to assign a AssociatedModel or AssociatedModel.id to an ActiveRecordModel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to build a helper method that will take keyword args and based on some logic will do something with them, here is an example:

```rb
def update_with_logic(widget:, user:)
  # do some logic here
  widget.user = user
end
```

Now this works perfectly fine, however, I would like to support `user` also being set to the user's ID.

However, if we send `user: 3` into our `update_with_logic` method, I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: User(#47287814961100) expected, got 3 which is an instance of Integer(#47287745166420)
```

If you try it the other way: `widget.user_id = user` and `user` is a `ActiveRecord::Model`, it will set `user_id` to `nil` (and not raise an exception)

This surprised me, as I can do the following in the ActiveRecord::Query setup without a problem:

```rb
userModel = User.find 3

# Looking up by user_id while sending a user model as the value
Widget.where(user_id: userModel).to_sql
# => SELECT "widgets".* FROM "widgets" WHERE "widgets"."user_id" = 3

# Looking up by user association while sending a user_id (integer) as the value
Widget.where(user: 3).to_sql
# => SELECT "widgets".* FROM "widgets" WHERE "widgets"."user_id" = 3
```

I've tried to use `widget.attributes = { user: user }` however, it has the same effects when `user = 3`. (Raises a ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch).

The only solution I found was to do the following:

```rb
widget.user_id = user.is_a?(User) ? user.id : user
```

The solution above works, however, it doesn't feel like a clean implementation. I'm hoping someone can recommend something more in line with *"The Rails Way®"* ;)

Comment: After some  more consideration, Not sure if you'd want this feature. Because if you supported saving a `user` via `user_id`, you would encourage developers to send different objects in. Say you need to access `user.full_name`, however, `user = 3`, you'd have to a bunch of checks to see what type of object `user` was. This seems like it would add way more complexity to the code (overall).

Comment: Even though I disagree with using this approach, I did want to see if I could build a concern that would support the implementation talked about (including @konstantin-strukov recommendation to ensure model is the expected model) Check out: https://gist.github.com/anlek/9f888518d3273508caffafdb1afea07c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can feed `ActiveRecord` with such a mess only because it does [some heavylifting](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f95c0b7e96eb36bc3efc0c5beffbb9e84ea664e4/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb#L1169) to build the proper query. There is literally no magic - all this convenient polymorphism is traded for the code complexity.

Your code with `try` is a bit dangerous - what if not an instance of User but any other model is provided (it will respond to `id` too)? You could make it more bulletproof, for example

```
case user
when Integer
  widget.user_id = user
when User
  widget.user = user
else
  raise "BOOM!"
end
```

But this is not ideal too - what if the user with the provided id doesn't exist? Sure, we could easily add the check (of just do smth like `widget.user = User.find(user)`), but do we really need all this accidental complexity?

If I were you I'd stop for a moment and ask myself a question: why is this method being called inconsistently? If we want it to assign a user to a widget why on Earth do we want to provide not a user but something else (or vice versa)? Is it really unavoidable?

In the wast majority of real-world cases the answer is "no": it is possible to make the necessary changes in the places where this method is being called so that it will always receive consistent parameters - either an instance of the User or a valid user id, - and keep the method itself clean and straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
The answer to your question of why support multiple `user` values is mainly that we have a team of 5 developers, and we like the "The Ruby Way" of if you think it should work that way, it will. This is something that Rails has done very well, and so we try to keep that going forward. Most of the time, we run with the expected signature (in this example it would be a `User` model. However, once in a while we don't want to load a user, especially when the logic part of the method doesn't really need to have a user model. It would be nice to just give it an ID.

Comment: I also appreciate the security concern about `try`, it never crossed my mind. You're correct that I would want to do something like  `widget.user_id = user.is_a?(User) ? user.id : user`. That way it would raise an error if `user` was a different model (or object).